# References to re-learn differentiation and integration

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations, integration

I'm looking to re-learn "differentiation and integration", it has really been a long time since I touched the subject.

I'm considering starting with Algebra then differentiation and integration.
Any gentle resource (books, online) about the subject?
*Consider me a "rookie".*

Comment: I hope someone will fish out a duplicate for this question.

Comment: @KannappanSampath [Feel free](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114646/looking-for-a-calculus-textbook)

Comment: @Chiron I personally recommend: Spivak's Calculus, Apostol's Calculus and maybe if you're up to it (it is rather challenging) Landau's Calculus.

Comment: @Peter T.off: After those books, he'll then want to look at the advanced calculus text by Loomis and Sternberg and the advanced calculus text by Nickerson, Spencer, and Steenrod!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro How did you manage to get through the Nickerson et. al. text? The typesetting is so horrible and the lack of an index (!) make it very difficult reading. The information contained therein looks pretty interesting - and uncommon - I don't know of any other text that covers the same topics. An suggestions for an alternative that, preferably, uses latex and has an index?

Comment: Here are some free calculus books: http://www.theassayer.org/cgi-bin/asbrowsesubject.cgi?class=Q#freeclassQAmg

Comment: @3Sphere: I've read very little in the Nickerson text (probably no more than a handful of pages), but I have noticed that its print quality seems to vary among the several copies I've seen in university libraries over the years. I first encountered it on the math/physics library shelves at UNC-Chapel Hill around 1977 (my first undergraduate year) and, not knowing any better at the time (no internet, etc.), I assumed this was the level of material that stronger Princeton Soph/Junior math students could handle. Here some reviews: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=370189

Comment: @3Sphere: **previous comment continued** A couple of years after this I learned from a faculty member who went to Harvard that the Loomis and Sternberg text was used for their honors advanced calculus course, but it was discontinued because students found the text too difficult (see my comments at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=245282 ). I've read more in the Loomis and Sternberg text than Nickerson (a few dozen pages somewhat carefully, not all at the beginning), but like the Nickerson text, I don't really know the book very well (or much of the material covered in it).

Answer (score 2):

These two books should be helpful:

Elliott Mendelson, **Schaum's 3,000 Solved Problems in Calculus** ($15.52 new)

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0071635343](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343)

Murray R. Spiegel and Robert Moyer, **Schaum's Outline of College Algebra**, 3rd edition by Spiegel ($11.74 new)

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0071635394](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635394)