# Best practice book for calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I tried with every inch in me to not ask a question such as this but I just couldn't resist asking this.

> What is *the* best Calculus practice book?

I tried looking around but couldn't find a decent consensus on one book or even a few. It would be great if someone could point me towards a book that has both challenging and fun problems and furthermore, allows the student to build a strong foundation while doing those problems.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I very much doubt you will find a few answers, it depends too much on material to cover and personal preferences. In any case, look over http://ocw.mit.edu, there you'll find much stuff like homework and exams with solutions. I personally like Chen's lecture notes <http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/ln.html> and the books by the Trillia Group <http://trillia.com>. Not too much _calculus_ oriented, but fun and challenging problems are found in the math olympiad sites, particularly those which have material for contestant preparation.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170196/suggest-books-in-calculus-to-improve-problem-solving-skills/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in 3k problems you should cover almost everything

[http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-000-Solved-Problems-Calculus/dp/0071635343/ref=pd_sim_b_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343)

Comment: In my experience, Schaum's books are collections of more drill-type problems, not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Andrew I'm looking for books that have easy problems at first but they build up into more harder problems later. Hopefully, the book you have provided does not have incredibly difficult problems but I shall give it a try, nonetheless.

Comment: @gekkostate Thanks for the specifics of what you are looking for. Schaum's outlines are quite user friendly. Since all the problems are solved, you can use it to your advantage to see if the solutions come easy to you or not, so you can pick the start level you want. On the other hand, even though you would have the solutions, once you get going, try not to look at them at least until you have written down (pencil on paper is important) how to at approach the problem or what you would like to know. Then look. Check the solutions after for confirmation or perhaps a different/better approach.

Answer (score 6):

- Collection of problems in analysis by B.P. Demidovich
- Problems in Mathematical Analysis  B.P. Demidovich

These books are very famous here in Brazil. It's very organized and easy to get addicted.

Comment: these are good books, but I don't think it's famous in Brazil.

Answer (score 3):

Problems in Calculus of One Variable, with Elements of Theory by IA Maron is good for problems as well as revising single variable calculus.

http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Problems_in_Calculus_of_One_Variable_wit.html?id=2svbSAAACAAJ

Answer (score 2):

How hard did you look? Just search "Calculus Textbook" in the search bar. I found the following links that you may find useful: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63504/suggest-textbook-on-calculus), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114646/looking-for-a-calculus-textbook), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/what-are-the-recommended-textbooks-for-introductory-calculus), ....

Comment: Yes but I am not looking for a textbook, rather I am looking for a book that has problems that will build my foundation and while I do these problems, I want to be able to solidify my foundation. I already have a decent textbook but I will look at the links you have provided.

Comment: Well if your just looking for a problem book why not go with Schaums book of 3000 problems. I believe that will help you out

Answer (score -1):

Try these two:

1. [Calculus: 1,001 Practice Problems For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Calculus-1-001-Practice-Problems-For-Dummies-Free-Online-Practice-.productCd-111849671X.html)
2. [Calculus Workbook For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Calculus-Workbook-For-Dummies.productCd-076458782X.html)

Answer (score -5):

1. Hard and imaginative problems **the whoascum county problem book**
2. the green/red book of math problems.