# calculus 1: books with examples/full solutions

Tags: calculus

I believe (and I think not the only one) a good way learning math is practicing.
Can you suggest me books offering examples/ excercies with solutions for calculus 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download this book in here [Schaum's 3,000 solved problems in calculus 2009](http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/view.php?id=598807) 
and you can see a lot of book in here [a lot of books about calculus](http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/search.php?search_type=magic&search_text=problems+in+calculus+&submit=Dig+for)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Schaum's 3000 Solved Problems in Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343). It has problems with explanations.

You can also check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295790/best-practice-book-for-calculus) which is similar to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to check http://www.stumblingrobot.com/index-of-solutions/solutions-to-calculus-exercises/
It has solutions for Tom M. Apostol Calculus Vol 1. An excellent book for Calculus/Analysis.