# book on real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, book-recommendation

could anyone suggest me a problem book that comprise interesting problems on topics like series , sequence , functional identities. a good problem book on real analysis is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Related: [Calculus 1: books with examples/full solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567062),
[Best practice book for calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295790),
[Exercise books in analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949197),
[Book recommendation for analysis problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1009371),
[Recommended Problem books for undergraduate Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2951319),
[https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170205/8297](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170196),
[Real analysis text books](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790213).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended Problem books for undergraduate Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951319/recommended-problem-books-for-undergraduate-real-analysis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Problems in Mathematical Analysis I, II and III by W. J. Kaczor and M. T. Nowak.

Other good book is Problems in mathematical analysis: B. P Demidovich.

And try to start solving problems from Bartle's book: Introduction to Real Analysis and Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol.