# Real Analysis Book recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Is there any exercise/solution book for undergrad intro to real Analysis book. I want to exercise on Limits, function , continuity and differentiation, but I didn't find books that provide a great deal of exercises with solutions. We got provided in the lecture with some exercises but they were not enough, especially that I understand math (I guess mostly everyone) by doing a lot of exercises. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to repeat my answer from another question: [Suggest books in calculus to improve problem solving skills](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170196#170205). But Demidovich, Kaczor-Nowak (three volumes) and Radulescu-Radulescu-Andreescu might be worth having a look.

Comment: You might check older posts on the site about this topic.You can browse a bit through the posts tagged [book-recommendation+real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+real-analysis) or [book-recommendation+calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+calculus). You will find several questions which have similar focus. To list some examples, you could have a look here:
[Calculus 1: books with examples/full solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567062),
...

Comment: ... [Best practice book for calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295790),
[Exercise books in analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949197),
[Book recommendation for analysis problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1009371),
[Recommended Problem books for undergraduate Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2951319),
[https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170205/8297](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170196),
[Real analysis text books](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790213).

Comment: My real analysis textbook at school is Introduction To Calculus And Analysis by Richard Courant and Fritz John.

Comment: @Divide1918: In case you're interested, there is a solutions manual (which is probably not very well known) for the Courant/John book --- Albert Abraham Blank, [**Problems in Calculus and Analysis**](https://archive.org/details/ProblemsInCalculusAndAnalysisAlbertBlank), John Wiley and Sons, 1966, x + 264 pages.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Cool thanks I might refer to that in the future

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended Problem books for undergraduate Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951319/recommended-problem-books-for-undergraduate-real-analysis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest *Problems in Analysis* by Bernard Gelbaum, but those exercises are quite hard, although no Lebesgue measure, integrals are involved, anyway, as long as there is solution, it is still an accessible problems book.