# Training Exercises for Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am a first Semester studyng Mathematics and i find that oftentimes I am am unable to solve a problem (in Analysis I) due to a lack in skill in simplifying, rewriting etc. various expressions to prove a desired result. 
I guess the best way to get better at this is to practice, so my question is if you know a good resource for exercises that focus on training these kinds of skills.

I am not sure if this question is appropriate so I will delete if it doesn't fit and second I only learned English in school so please forgive grammar mistakes.

Comment: Which book are you studying from?  That would make a difference as far as what problems would help.

Comment: I am using Hildebradt Analysis I.

Comment: Although you have tagged the question (real-analysis), the name Analysis I suggest that you might actually want calculus. You might check some of these older posts:
[What are some problem books in Single variable calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1997094), 
[Book recommendation for analysis problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1009371),
[Suggest books in calculus to improve problem solving skills](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170196), etc.

Comment: You might try to browse a bit through the questions tagged [calculus+book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus+book-recommendation) or [real-analysis+book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis+book-recommendation) and you might find a few other similar posts. And if you mainly want exercises for manipulations with expressions - not directly with calculus - you might also check questions tagged ...

Comment: ... [algebra-precalculus+book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus+book-recommendation). . Some post around this topic: [Which books for refreshing high school algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23740), [I want to study mathematics ahead of high school, but I found that I'm rusty on the elementary stuff](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98092) or [Looking for a good precalculus/algebra reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44240)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)